# PropertyNotFoundException in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Am getting this error in my application

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'survey_id' not found on type com.moh.forms.MOH731
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:229)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:206)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:317)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
```

This is my MOH731.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int survey_id;

public MOH731 (int survey_id, String uname)

@Override
public String toString()
{
return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
public Integer getId() {
return survey_id;
}

public void setId(Integer survey_id) {
this.survey_id=survey_id;
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Use `id` in your JSP instead of `survey_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your getter & setter is wrong.

By convention it must be:

```
public Integer getSurvey_id() {
   return survey_id;
}

public void setSurvey_id(Integer survey_id) {
   this.survey_id=survey_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You getter and setter naming convention should be as per the `Id` property

Either change `private int survey_id;` to `private int Id;`

Or

```
public Integer getId() {
return survey_id;
}

public void setId(Integer survey_id) {
this.survey_id=survey_id;
}
```

to

```
public Integer getSurvey_id() {
   return survey_id;
}

public void setSurvey_id(Integer survey_id) {
   this.survey_id=survey_id;
}
```